# Micro-ECC value possible?

Tags: c, stm32, private-key

I've created a ecc public/private key pair on a stm32f767zi with 216mhz clock speed. For the generation step it took me only about 0.002449ms on average.
I've used the following command to generate both keys `uECC_make_key(public1, private1, curves[c])`

Is it possible that just such a little amount of time is needed to generate a public and private key pair?

Thank you very much.

Comment: 2.5 micro seconds for that function to return?  at 216mhz dont you need ~0.5us per instruction?  This seems like it would take more than 5 instructions.  If anything its doing a lookup and just moving stuff around, or im way off base and have no idea what im talking about.

Comment: @Bwebb you need ~4.6 ns per clock cycle, so you get about 540 cycles in 2.5 uS,

Comment: @Colin so you think the result could be possible?

Comment: I have no idea what that function is doing, so can't say.

Comment: @Colin Thanks for the correction.  ECC is elliptic curve crypto and when i did this in college, multiplication was implemented as iterated ECC addition, which was complicated and probably implemented crappy from students.  Since it powers cell phone crypto, i wouldn't be surprised if someone go a Phd by making this library efficient, and the next guy makes it more efficient, etc for ~30+ years, until it works to about what you're seeing.  I haven't looked into the implementation, you can check the asm if you want to count instructions, you have 540 of them in the average exec path.

Comment: The time is a function of the size of the elliptic curve domain parameters, and of course the implementation. 540 cycles seems pretty fast to generate a secure, random, ecc key pair.

Comment: check the return value of the function